# Nashorn (es6) corrupted function scope

Tags: java, ecmascript-6, java-11, nashorn

I am currently investigating following issue in Nashorn js scripting engine and I'd appreciate your input.
Following code snippet fails execution (code in Kotlin):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val brokenScript = """
        function fn() {
            const object1 = { "name": "Pepa" };
            print(object1.name);
            const descriptor1 = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object1, 'name');
            print(descriptor1.configurable);
            print(eval("3+1"));
        }
        fn();
    """.trimIndent()
    NashornScriptEngineFactory()
            .getScriptEngine("--no-deprecation-warning", "--language=es6", "--log=compiler:finest,fields,recompile:fine")
            .let { (it as Compilable).compile(brokenScript) }
            .also { script -> script.eval() }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "descriptor1" is not defined in <eval> at line number 8
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:477)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:461)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:517)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:103)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:19)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt)
Caused by: <eval>:8 ReferenceError: "descriptor1" is not defined
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:278)
    at jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.AccessorProperty.checkUndeclared(AccessorProperty.java:571)
...
```

**Observations:**

- issue is influenced by **eval** function - ommiting it from script helps - also need to be nested in function - works fine at top level
- issue is influenced by **Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor** function - ommiting it from script helps
- issue is influenced by scoping - changing variable declaration from scoped (**const/let**) to unscoped **var** helps
- output log contains `caught RewriteException [pp=3, type=object, value='Pepa')]`

**Current hypothesis:**

**Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor** function raises **UnwarrantedOptimismException** that forces the function to recompile.
Scope of recompiled script is corrupted. Usually the scope is manipulated by **eval** function usage so it can declare variables - maybe this is resolved incorrectly during the runtime recompilation.
Accessing scoped variables fails.

**What outcome I hope for?(in order of preference)**

- it works just as when executed in node - obviously
- issue is identified at compile time without turning off es6 features
- disabling **eval** function prevents the issue - I tried this by removing eval from Bindings object but script is corrupted at compilation phase and modified Bindings are passed later to `script.eval(bindings)` - so the script still fails before reaching eval line
- (this is actually what I try to avoid) bypassing issue by turning off es6 features (removing **--language=es6** - this forces the script to fail at compile time due to usage of scoped variables (**const/let**)

(I am aware that nashorn is deprecated and will be removed.)

Answer (score 0):

We also had similar problem with Nashorn and JDK 9+. It seems like `optimistic types` causes this problem. Try disabling optimistic types for Nashorn

```
.getScriptEngine("--no-deprecation-warning", "--language=es6", "--log=compiler:finest,fields,recompile:fine", "--optimistic-types=false")
```

Ref: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/196